# .PasteSpecial Error PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have this piece of code:

```
If tempWorkSheet2.Range(Ava(Index) & "31").Value <> "0" Then tempWorkSheet2.Range(Ava(Index) & "31").Copy
            mainWorkbook2.Sheets("Vysledek").Range("D" & mainWorkbook2.Sheets("Vysledek").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Thought whenever i run it it says this error message:

[image: Error message]

Anyone who could help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Your second line will always run, even if you didn't copy anything.

Comment: I dont get it. Is that the error?

Comment: You are using a "inline" If, so the If condition does not apply to the second line. It will be evaluated every time the code is run, while the "copy" will occurs only if the condition is true.

Comment: OHhhh i see. That is exactly the case, fixed it now works like a charm. Thanks!